# How to resolve this error - there is no attribute "onFocus"

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting an error called there is no attribute "onFocus".
I have a code as follows:

`<input name="name" id="name" class="small required name" type="text" value="Name:" onFocus="if(this.value='Name:'){this.value=''}" />`

I tried validating my site in http://validator.w3.org/, and I got these errors.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: the w3c validator is interesting but fairly useless in that it dumps a ton of errors that every browser can handle. Remember even if you are 100% w3c compatible, you can still have rendering issues with real world browsers. Is it really worth the effort?

Comment: @Byron Whitlock, avoiding tag soup makes rendering way more predictable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attribute name is `onfocus`, with a small `f`. That's what the validator is complaining about.